# Render function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have an ajax request on my webpage, which returns views depending if the data is validated or not. This was working perfectly on Laravel 5.4, but I have had to downgrade on my server to Laravel 5.0, and now it is throwing errors. My ajax request does other things if the data isn't valid, and it works as expected. So the problem is with this render function

```
//Controller Method for my ajax request 
     //when data is valid
        return ["view" => view("example")->render(), "isValid" => true];
     //when data is valid
        return ['isValid' => false];
```

Now when my data isn't valid, it behaves as expected. But it throws an error when returning this view. Any tips?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you have to downgrade from 5.4 to 5.0? Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: The error I get thrown is the my ajax request in my jquery:

so `$.ajax({
 //other info
success: function(data)
error: alert("Error");
})`
In my dev tools on chrome, the error I receive is a 500 Internal Service Error

Comment: @ChrisForrence the server I am with only has Laravel 5.0, and I was working on another one with 5.4, but now the one with 5.4 is shutting down, so I have to move it to Laravel 5.0

Comment: Alright, so what's appearing in your logs? (/path/to/project/storage/logs/)

Comment: Yea so the error is: local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception' in ..

Comment: Can you add the full error message into your question? It almost sounds like it's an issue with your "example" view. Perhaps there's a blade directive in there that isn't available in 5.0?

Comment: Yea it turned out that In my view, I was putting in a {{}} function only in an advanced version of a php. Thanks for all of your help @ChrisForrence

Answer (score 0):

You should switch back to laravel 5.4. If you like any features from older versions of laravel: you can still access them at https://laravelcollective.com/
I am guessing your laravel version is not compatible with your code. (Check out laravel 5.0's documentation if you cannot switch back)

Comment: Yea man it sucks downgrading, but I am unable to since there are a thousand applications on, and all run on Laravel 5.0